# How can I calculate a specific diameter hole (28.5 mm) for a hyperboloid center opening when it's Z=0

Tags: parametric, python, quadrics

How can I calculate a specific diameter hole (28.5 mm) for a hyperboloid center opening when it's Z=0

The arrows point to where z=0 and the 28.5mm hole should be.

I'm using python

[image]

The snippet of python code / formula I'm using is below:

```
        u = 8*(i/num_x-1/2)
        v = 2*math.pi*(j/(num_y-1)-1/2)

        x = uval_a*math.sqrt(1+u*u)*math.cos(v)
        y = uval_a*math.sqrt(1+u*u)*math.sin(v)
        z = uval_b*(u)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those constants -- `uval_a` and `uval_b` -- serve exactly that purpose.

`uval_a` is the radius of the center circle, so you shoudl set

`uval_a = 28.5 / 0.5`

assuming that you're working in mm units everywhere. What about `uval_b`? That tells you how tall the hyperboloid is.